# for x in range(y) vs. while loop: Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm attempting the Project Euler questions again, and on [problem 2](http://projecteuler.net/problem=2), I am being asked to find the sum of all even numbers in the Fibonacci sequence under 4 million. I am able to do that using the code below using the While loop (shown as a comment in the code), but not using the for loop (which gives me enormous numbers and takes 'c' way further than 4 million.

Why is the for loop not working here?

Thanks.

```
def fibo():
    z=[]
    a=1
    b=1
    c=0
    for c in range(0,4000000):    #doesn't work; works with while (c<4000000)
        c = a+b
        if c%2 == 0 and c<4000000:
            z.append(c)
        a=b
        b=c
        print c
    print 'sum is',sum(z)

fibo()
```

Comment: The modification you do to `c` in `for` loop is not taken in consideration on next iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The for loop doesn't mean "stop when `c == 4000000`". It means "iterate over the sequence `range(4000000)`, which is a list of numbers from 0 to 3999999, and run the loop body once with `c` set to each element of the sequence".

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty is that `range()` returns a list (or an iterator in Python 3). Each pass through the loop gets the next number from the range. Assigning a different value to `c` doesn't do anything because `for` isn't looking at `c` for anything, it's just getting the next number from the range and putting it in `c`. The value of `c` is entirely irrelevant to the `for` loop.

You can write your own iterator that allows you to use `send()` to reset the iterator value, but this is kind of tricky to write. You might as well use a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is iterating over the entire range from 0 to 4M, blowing away the changes you made to it within each iteration of the loop.  You can't really do this with any simple `for` loop I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that every 3rd Fibonacci number is even. You can prove this by induction. Also the Fibonacci numbers are defined through a recurrence relation with characteristic polynomial x^2-x-1. That is they have a closed form solution F_n = a*c^n + b*d^n with c and d the zeros of the characteristic polynomial. The resulting identity is also known as Binet's Formula. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) for the details.

It follows that the desired result is a sum of two geometric series. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) will tell you the closed form for geometric series.

The point is that you can compute the desired result without iteration. In my opinion this is what this problem is really about.

Answer (score 0):

You're updating `c` inside of the for loop:  `c = a+b`.  Use a different variable.